# Call methods in main method

Tags: java, methods

This is my main method that gets 3 integers from command line and I parse then in my validating method.

However I have one operation method that calls 3 other methods, but i don't know what type of data and how many I have to put in my `operatinMethod()` cause switch only gets one); AND also in my `mainMethod()` for calling the `operationMehod()` itself?

Please let me know if i'm not clear? Thanx!

Main method:

Comment: what's with the for() loop that does nothing?

Comment: Do you want to perform each operation only if validation success on all the three arguments?

Comment: Could you give example arguments and the expected result?

Comment: @w4rumy I updated my whole codes, please check it out!

Comment: @Niloo there is still no example call of your program in your question. I think this would help us a lot in understanding what you want to achieve. (BTW I think your updated question with all code is more confusing now than before)

Comment: @Niloo please see my ans let me know is that compromising your que?

Comment: Still that for loop thing is a puzzle for us @Niloo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to perform the following operation

```
 CountPrimes(int) ,   getFactorial(int) and isLeapYear(int)` ....
```

Now tell me what values you will be getting as `command line arguments`. If you want to perform all the three operations then pass change the case value and give the input value

```
  performOperations(int value, int caseConstant)
```

Above statement will get two arguments one is the value and another one is the constatnt to select the operation.

```
 if(validateInput(args[0],args[1],args[2])) {

   performOperations(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),1);

   performOperations(Integer.parseInt(args[1]),2);

   performOperations(Integer.parseInt(args[2]),3);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
   /*whatever here*/
   try{
   performOperation(Integer.parseInt(args[3])); /*if option is supplied with the arguments*/ 
   }catch(Exception e){ }
}
private static void performOperations(int option) {
    switch(option) {
  case 1: // count Prime numbers
      countPrimes(a);
      break;
  case 2: // Calculate factorial
      getFactorial(b);
      break;

  case 3: // find Leap year
      isLeapYear(c);
      break;

   } 
}
```

Comment: @Niloo what does your validateInput() function do and return?

Comment: if those entries are numbers!!! in main method I call them with :            if(validateInput(args[0],args[1],args[2])){
            performOperations(**what i suppose to put here?**);

Comment: @Niloo I am still unclear as to WHAT YOU ARE TRYING TO DO. How can I help you if I don't know what you're upto?

Comment: I just update my code... my OperationMethod should call 3 other Methods, which they each get 3 different numbers from Command line Argument!  Finally, I have to call operationMethod(); and i don't know what type of data and howmany i have to put in :(

Answer (score 0):

Command line args recieves input as `String []` and  the values can be parsed to your required data types and can pass it as function parameters.See here about [Command line args parsing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 }
```

Correct me if 'm wrong :)

Comment: you are not wrong, but i have 3 integers that i need to pass to operationMethod and in my main method!! the both have to be the same!

Answer (score 0):

You put the name of the variable you are evaluating the value for in this switch statement switch(**what i suppose to put here?**)
For e.g. when you say case 1, then that 1 should be coming from your variable.

When you are defining the method, you just need to pass the parameters whose values you are evaluating and then you can may be pass that variable to the switch statement?

Comment: but switch(); only gets one var and I have 3 vars fr my 3 integers?!!

Comment: pass an array to the switch statement and then put that statement inside a for loop and that way you can iterate through all the variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this approach:

I avoid using global variables, they are not necessary, I assume that you always are trying to do:

- countPrimes with the first argument
- Calculate factorial with the second
- and find Leap year with the third

The code should be something like:

```
public class Test {
// Global Constants
        final static int MIN_NUMBER = 1;
        final static int MAX_PRIME = 10000;
        final static int MAX_FACTORIAL = 12;
        final static int MAX_LEAPYEAR = 4000;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            if (validInput(args)) {
                performOperations(args);
            }
        }

        private static boolean validInput(String[] args) {
            if (args.length == 3 && isInteger(args[0]) && isInteger(args[1]) && isInteger(args[2]) &&
                    withinRange(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),MIN_NUMBER, MAX_PRIME) &&
                    withinRange(Integer.parseInt(args[1]),MIN_NUMBER, MAX_FACTORIAL) &&
                    withinRange(Integer.parseInt(args[2]),MIN_NUMBER, MAX_LEAPYEAR) )
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        //Check the value within the specified range
        private static boolean withinRange(int userInput, int min, int max) {
            boolean isInRange = true;
            if (userInput < min || userInput > max) {
                isInRange = false;
            }
            return isInRange;
        }

        private static boolean isInteger(String value) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(value);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //Perform operations
        private static void performOperations(String[] args) {
            countPrimes(args[0]);
            getFactorial(args[1]);
            isLeapYear(args[2]);
        }
}
```